# Binding parameters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, binding, parameters

I'm trying to learn about binding parameters in MySQL. I tried this test but I'm getting the error "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object".

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the updated code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $value1, $value2, $value3);
$value1 = "test1";
$value2 = "test2";
$value3 = "test3";
$stmt->execute();
```

Here is the `connect()` function:

```
function connect(){
    global $conn;
    $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `connec()` function. Where do you set `$conn`?

Comment: You don't need to bind you could just pass the variables in an array into the execute. As is I don't think the bind can decipher the `type` from the individual variable values.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`?

Comment: mysqli. I updated the question with the connect function

Comment: All right I just figured what's going on here : you defined your mysqli instance into a global variable that isn't accessible out of your function because you don't declare it again. You need to add `global $conn;` in top of your script and now it should be allright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>To bind params in a prepared query in PDO, pass an array containing your params to the execute function :</strike>

```
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array($value1, $value2, $value3));
```

**UPDATE**

For the mysqli version :

```
connect();
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->bind_param('sss', $value1, $value2, $value3);
$result->execute();
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: No it isn't wrong. There is few way to bind params, you just mixed two ways of them. You can of course use `bindParam` if you want, but not `bind_param`, which is a mysqli function.

Comment: I tried this: connect();
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array($bind));
and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: You need to pass an array, not a string (if you didn't changed `$bind`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am I not doing exactly what w3schools is doing in the "mysqli" example (the first one)? If not, can you point out the difference?

Comment: All right figured now that you want to use mysqli. See my updated answer. You need to pass your params in bind_param as separate parameters, not as a string.

Comment: Where do you define the values as a string (or integer)?

Comment: I tried this and it's not working: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$field1 = "test1";
$field2 = "test2";
$field3 = "test3";
$bind = array();
$bind[] = "sss";
$bind[] = "$field1";
$bind[] = "$field2";
$bind[] = "$field3";

connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($bind));

Comment: No ignore the first answer - I was showing you how to do it with PDO, not mysqli. Check the updated version - it shows how to do it with mysqli.

Comment: I also tried this: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$value1 = "test1";
$value2 = "test2";
connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $value1, $value2, $value3);
$stmt->execute();
$value3 = "test3";

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have now. It will be easier to see if there is something wrong (on your last comment I just see the beginning of your code, not the binding part).

Comment: Ah, the problem was with the field names in the actual table. Your answer works! Sorry about that!